# Cereal does not support raw pointers

Tags: c++, serialization, cereal

**Edit:** The question title was based on a deep missunderstanding of the compiler error I got. I was (sillyly) assuming the error was, that I tried to deserialize to an object I declared inside of the function. This was utterly wrong. I didn't do enough debug efforts myself or I could have found out what was wrong. So the title was quite missleading and I changed it. Thanks to Андрей Беньковский for helping.

---

I'm writing Serialization functions for 3D Models in my engine using cereal, which proves to be really efficient and easy to use.
So far everything worked great when I tested (de-)serializing a simple Mesh. 
But now I'm trying to deserialize another class but ran in a problem I don't get.

```
void loadFile(std::string filepath)
{
    DescriptionFile file;

    {
        ifstream stream = ifstream(filepath, std::ifstream::binary);
        PortableBinaryInputArchive archive(stream);
        archive(file);
        stream.close();
    }
}
```

This is my class, that should be deserialized:

```
struct DescriptionFile 
{
public:
    DescriptionFile(){}

    map<string, MeshDescription*> meshDescriptions;
    map<string, ModelDescription*> modelDescriptions;

public:
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & archive)
    {
        archive(meshDescriptions, modelDescriptions);
    }
};
```

It gives me compiler error:
Cereal does not support serializing raw pointers - please use a smart pointer
Even though it's not a pointer. In another part of the code something similar works just fine. I'd be glad if somebody could help me solve this.

Comment: `filepath` is `std::string`? Please edit your question to indicate the type.

Comment: [using namespace is evil](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards#using-namespace-std)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I never used Cereal, but it looks like it expects you to use something like this:

`map<string, unique_ptr<MeshDescription> >`

To get [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) I usually `#include <memory>`

From [cereal documentation](http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/pointers.html):

cereal supports serializing smart pointers but not dumb pointers (that is to say raw pointers, such as `int *`) or references. Pointer support can be found by including `<cereal/types/memory.hpp>`.

May be it means you have to include their header instead of the standard.

P.S. When your object owns resources (e.g. dynamically allocated `MeshDescription`) always delegate resource management (allocation, deallocation, copying, etc) to a separate class (smart pointer, collection, wrapper, etc). See [rule of 0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: This would probably work, but I'm still wondering WHY my code does not compile. As I said, I used something similar (practically the same, but with a different struct) works absolutely fine without complaining. I want to use the real solution or understand what's happening and don't use some workaround for strange behaviour.

Comment: P.S. I'm already doing this. The code I've posted is located in a class called RessourceManager.

Comment: Okay, I'm stupid. I though the error was inside of the loadFile function while indeed it was the fact that I'm using a map consisting of a pointer as value. Thanks for your help.

Comment: 1. `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` are managed pointers from the standard library. They are highly tested and optimized. I'd recommend you using this classes to manage your pointers unless there is a very good reason to create your own. 2. You are misunderstanding the whole point of resource management: each instance of a resource manager should manage only one instance of a resource, not a collection of resources. Try it and see how much safer and simpler code you'll get in result.

Comment: 1. I know what smart pointers are and where to use them, I just missunderstood the compiler error I got. 2. There's a reason I need all of my ressources (at least of some kinds) in one place/class.

Comment: What reason? Why can't you use `std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<MeshDescription>>` or something similar?